# Time-series window query for calculating rolling average across group by subquery is inaccurate due to missing rows

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, window-functions

I'm trying to generate a rolling average based on a generated time series joined with a subquery on each day of the time series. However, the subquery occasionally does not have a result for a given day, and hence it does not return a row for said day. This breaks the rolling average calculation since it's based on preceding/following rows. It still calculates, but the calculation is wrong since it's not counting "0" days since those rows aren't present.

```sql
SELECT
    d::date AS day,
    updates.login as login,
    avg(coalesce(updates.counts, 0)) over (order by date(d) rows between 3 preceding and 3 following) as rollingavg
from generate_series(date '${from}' - 3, date '${to}' + 3, interval '1' DAY) AS t(d)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        date(item.updated_at) AS day,
        u.login,
        count(date(item.updated_at)) AS counts
    FROM
        user_item as item
        inner join user u ON u.id = item.user_id
    WHERE
        item.updated_at >= (date '${from}' - 3)
        item.updated_at <= (date '${to}' + 3)
    GROUP by day, login 
) updates ON updates.day = t.d
```

If I remove the `login` from the group by clause and modify the query to fit, it appears to work, but that's only because there is enough data that no day goes without at least one update. In the off chance there were a day without an update, this would experience the same problem.

My initial thought was to join a generated table that is essentially a cross join between the time series and every possible author, or possibly modify my `from generate_series` to represent such a table that includes a baseline '0' count for every user on every day, but something about that feels wrong.

Am I on the right path?

EDIT: Some simplified sample data to make it a bit more obvious what I'm getting at. **This is focused purely on the subquery since that is where the problem begins**:

User:

| id | login |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | userA |
| 2 | userB |

UserItem:

| updated_at | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| '2020-01-01' | 1 |
| '2020-01-01' | 2 |
| '2020-01-02' | 1 |
| '2020-01-03' | 2 |

The desired result is as follows:

| date | user | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2020-01-01 | userA | 1 |
| '2020-01-01 | userB | 1 |
| '2020-01-02 | userA | 1 |
| '2020-01-02 | userB | 0 |
| '2020-01-03 | userA | 0 |
| '2020-01-03 | userB | 1 |

But what I'm getting:

| date | user | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2020-01-01 | userA | 1 |
| '2020-01-01 | userB | 1 |
| '2020-01-02 | userA | 1 |
| '2020-01-03 | userB | 1 |

Comment: Can you provide sample data and the desired result?

Comment: @bbaird added!! I also realize that I probably should have limited the scope of the question purely to the subquery...

Comment: Yes, you're on the right path! I generally like to create a base range of rows at the lowest level so I have all "dimensional" values in the result set as early as possible in the query. In some cases it may be easier to fill them in at the end, or even do so in the display layer of an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lennart mentioned, you'll need to `CROSS JOIN` your generated series with your users to create the required combinations of `(Login,Date)`:

```
SELECT
  U.Login
 ,t.Date::date AS Day
 ,COUNT(UserItem.UserId) AS Count
 ,AVG(COUNT(UserItem.UserId)) OVER (PARTITION BY U.Login ORDER By t.Date ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING) AS RollingAvg
FROM
  "User" U
CROSS JOIN
  generate_series(date '2020-01-01' - 3, date '2020-01-01' + 3, interval '1' DAY) AS t(date)
LEFT JOIN
  UserItem UserItem
    ON UserItem.UserId = U.UserId
        AND UserItem.Updated_At = t.Date
GROUP BY
  U.Login
 ,t.Date
ORDER BY
  U.Login
 ,t.Date
```

You can restrict to only those users with activity in the date range by adding:

```
WHERE
  U.UserId IN
    (
      SELECT
        UserId
      FROM
        UserItem
      WHERE
        Updated_At >= date '2020-01-01' - 3 
        AND Updated_At <= date '2020-01-01' + 3
    )
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6f349e88291c0a032e73b780da98813c).

Comment: If you ever find yourself in Minneapolis, you've got a beer on me.

Comment: @James I'm in Saint Paul, so once the quarantine is done I'll take you up on it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need the generate_series part if you use range instead of rows:

```
SELECT
    d::date AS day,
    updates.login as login,
    avg(coalesce(updates.counts, 0)) over (order by to_char(d, 'J') RANGE between 3 preceding and 3 following) as rollingavg
from (
    SELECT
        date(item.updated_at) AS day,
        u.login,
        count(date(item.updated_at)) AS counts
    FROM
        user_item as item
        inner join user u ON u.id = item.user_id
    WHERE
        item.updated_at >= (date '${from}' - 3)
        item.updated_at <= (date '${to}' + 3)
    GROUP by day, login 
) updates
```

I used to_char(d, 'J') to map date to an integer ([JULIAN DAY](https://database.guide/convert-a-date-to-julian-day-in-postgresql/))

Comment: The problem is happening within the subquery, not the outer window function. I added some additional data to help clarify, and might rephrase the whole query to make it clearer. Thanks for taking your time on this!

Comment: Create a db<>fiddle with data that demonstrates the problem and I will have a look

Comment: Ok, you need generate_series after all

Comment: You also need the full domain of users that you can cross join with t(d), then left join with your subquery